# How to render the array of data in dropdown list

Tags: reactjs

how to render the array of data in dropdown list

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.getPackage();        
    await this.setState({
      packageList: this.props.packages.packageList
    })

    let packageList = [];
    this.state.packageList.map(items => {
      // console.log("items", items);
      packageList.push({"packages":items.name})
    })
}
```

Comment: This is not enough to know your issue and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your class component looks like this, you can use destucturing to get the value from this.state. Then, render different < option > using `map` function.

```
class YourClassComponent {

    //some other logic

    render = () =>
    {
        const { packageList } = this.state;

        return (
            <select>
            {packageList.map((eachPackageList,index) => (
                 <option key={i} value={eachPackageList.name}>{eachPackageList.name}</option>)
            )}
            </select>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: great !! @tsecheukfung01